# Why does Unity use a Service Locator?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, unity-container, service-locator

I have seen this line of code in several tutorials for using Unity in asp.net mvc3. I was under the impression that Service Locator is an anti-pattern and not best practice. Is this Service Locator something other than the anti-pattern defined, or is this line of code / this implementation considered bad practice.

```
ServiceLocator.SetLocatorProvider(() => new UnityServiceLocator(Container));
```

Comment: I've seen this used a lot too, in the Prism StockTrader RI, they use the ServiceLocator with MEF too. I was also under the impression it was an anti-pattern, hence am surprised to see it in a RI. I do believe this is the same Service Locator pattern implementation as the anti-pattern defined.

Comment: You got it backwards: in you example it's not Unity that is using service locator, but rather your code plug's in unity to asp.net mvc3 via service locator. The debates about Service Locator pattern are of religious nature. asp.net mvc team had to provide a way to use your favourite DI container and this is the way they've implemented it. Think of alternatives. Here is some more insight to the issue http://blog.ploeh.dk/2011/08/25/ServiceLocatorRolesVsMechanics.aspx

Comment: @zespri - so not all Unity implementations use a Service Locator?

Comment: There is only one Unity implementation known to me. It does not *use* service locator. It's up to you to use it as service locator if you are so inclined (even if Unity did not support it explicitly), but it does support it for the cases like this.

Comment: @zespri - I would very much like to avoid using service locator, do you know of any tutorials out there for asp.net mvc3 that show a simple unity setup without service locator?

Comment: Look here at the excellent under the hood look at how DI is wired up to asp.net. http://bradwilson.typepad.com/blog/2010/07/service-location-pt1-introduction.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is the same anti-patten that people talk about. All that line is doing is setting the service locator provider to be an instance of UnityServiceLocator, i.e. to use the Unity implementation of the ISerivceLocator. Optionally if you would like you can have your own implementation is IServiceLocator and use that instead of UnityServiceLocator.

Using Service Locator is considered a bad practice for various reasons as listed [here](http://blog.ploeh.dk/2010/02/03/ServiceLocatorIsAnAntiPattern.aspx)

Comment: I agree Service Locator is bad practice, I just wasn't sure if this was being used in name only.

Comment: If you are using an IOC container, how do you find the container ?

Comment: It has its place, see the other answer, it frees up your code from being directly tied to a particular DI implementation.

Comment: @philsoady I believe the answer for desktop applications is to add a constructor parameter of type IUnityContainer to any class that needs the container (see http://mvvmandunity.codeplex.com/). For other application types it might not be possible to do that, hence the service locator. Personally I would say using it solely to get the DI container would be acceptable if there is no other choice.

Answer (score 13):

Old question, but for the benefit of others:

While I absolutely agree with the mantra "Service Location is an anti-pattern", there are definitely exceptions to that rule.

When you use Dependency Injection (like Unity) then, yes, certainly don't use ServiceLocator and only use constructor injection for all your service classes. (Also don't use "new" for anything other than value objects like DTOs.)

However, there are cases where you simply can't use constructor injection and then the only way to get access to a service is to use a workaround to access your Unity container directly, and in such cases, ServiceLocator is a good standard way to accomplish that. This is the case when the class isn't instantiated by you (or more specifically, it isn't instantiated by Unity) but by the .NET framework for example.

A few simple examples of where ServiceLocator might be useful, is to get access to services registered in your Unity container from:

1. an implementation of a WCF IEndpointBehavior or IClientMessageInspector
2. an implementation of a WPF IValueConverter
3. or you may not necessarily even want to get access to "services" from the class, but you simply want to write code that is unit-testable, but for some reason the class can't be instatiated at all (or not easily) because it would normally be constructed by the .NET Framework, so you extract your custom code into a class that is testable, and resolve it in the non-testable class using the ServiceLocator.

Note that this line is not ideal:

```
ServiceLocator.SetLocatorProvider(() => new UnityServiceLocator(Container));
```

The ServiceLocator.Current property is going to execute the delegate provided every time you access Current, i.e. a new UnityServiceLocator is going to get created every time. Instead, you probably want to do this:

```
IServiceLocator locator = new UnityServiceLocator(container);
ServiceLocator.SetLocatorProvider(() => locator);
```

Answer (score 7):

If you create a framework which is designed to be container agnostic the service locator (although it should be a No-Go in an application) is an additional layer of indirection that allows you to swap out Unity for something different. In addition the use of the service locator does not enforce the use of DI for applications that use that framework.